# Definition of restriction maps of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, schemes

I understand that for Spec $A$ the restriction map is defined in a natural way. Given $V \subset U \subset Spec \ A = X$ open sets, for $f \in O_X (U)$ we define $f|_V$ by restricting the domain to $V$. Now scheme is defined by locally ringed space where every point has an affine open neighborhood. I am guessing that one can deduce that the restrictio maps on schemes also is just given by restricting the domains... how can I show this? thank you.

Comment: Can you state your question more precisely?  Which "restriction maps" are you talking about, exactly?  What do you mean by "restricting the domains"?

Comment: @EricWofsey I think I had things not understood correctly. In Hartshorne for the definition of Spec $A$, he defines the structure sheaf to be functions $f$ from open set $U$ to the disjoint union of localized rings. The restriction map say from $U$ to $V \subset U$ simply restricts the domain of $f$ making the function defined on $V$. I somehow thought that the structure sheaf of any scheme $X$ is like this, i.e. functions from $U$ to some disjoint union and all restriction maps are just restricting the domains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a arbitrary topological space such that  $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a scheme then $\mathcal{O}_X$ is just a sheaf such that $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is a ring for all open subset $U$ of $X$ so the restriction maps for the scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ are defined exactly the same as how we define for sheaves .